# Difference between @model.Name and @Html.DisplayFor(m => model.Name)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on web-application, it's my first time using asp.net mvc core 2.0.
I'm Learning from any tutorials, but everywhere different approaches with model print, I can't understand why there a lot of way for just print.

What is the difference between the two approaches:

```
<td>
   @item.Name
</td> 
<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
```

And which one is better?

Comment: I'm not a really a guru in ASP.NET MVC, but I believe the `@model.Name` notation just outputs the data, possibly using `.ToString()` on the value, while `@Html.DisplayFor()` will use the configured output rendering template for the type. So if you define an output rendering template for all your `DateTime` values, it will be applied whenever you use `@Html.DisplayFor()`, but it won't affect your output if you directly use `@model.YourDate`

Comment: Read about ASP.NET MVC Display templates here: https://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

Comment: @marc_s , wow that's so useful link, thank you a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a custom display template for any given data type, using `@Html.DisplayFor()` will respect that custom display template and render your code as you wished.

Using `@Model.YourField` directly will just simply call `.ToString()` on that field and output whatever that call returns.

Try this:

**Models/IndexModel.cs**:

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller/HomeController.cs**:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IndexModel model = new IndexModel {HireDate = new DateTime(2015, 8, 15)};
    return View(model);
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        Output directly: @Model.HireDate
        <br/><br/>
        Output via DisplayFor: @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.HireDate)
    </div>
</div>
```

And finally the custom display template:

**Views/DisplayTemplates/DateTime.cshtml**:

```
@{
    <span class="datetime">@Model.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy / HH:mm")</span>
}
```

Your output will now be:

```
Output directly: 15.08.2015 00:00:00            // Output from Model.HireDate.ToString();

Output via DisplayFor: Aug 15, 2015 . 00:00     // Output as defined in your custom display template
```

Which one is *better* now really depends on what you want to do:

- typically, I'd prefer to use `@Html.DisplayFor()`, since normally, if I went through the trouble of defining a custom display template, I probably want to use that, too
- but if you just need the "raw" output, without custom rendering, you can always also use `@model.YourField` directly

So it's really a question of what you want / need - pick the one most suited to your needs / requirements!

Comment: _Using @Model.YourField directly will just simply call .ToString() on that field and output whatever that call returns_ IIRC this will also wrap the string around `MvcString` class, which will properly escape the string (i.e. replace < to `&lt;` etc. )

Comment: or [HtmlString](https://github.com/aspnet/HtmlAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions/HtmlString.cs) can't remember exactly, its one if it. It encodes the input to prevent html and scrip injection.